# Kohana 3.2: class Model_Database not found

Tags: php, kohana-3.2

I am getting this error when I try to run my code on server.

The error is for model file `cities.php`

The code in cities.php is as follows:

```
class Model_Cities extends Model_Database {}
```

It works fine on local server. But gives error for production server.

Answer (score 1):

Is kohana database module enabled on server in bootstrap.php?
Usually that file is slightly different on production than on local and sometimes you can forget to enable additional module etc.

You could check all loaded modules using:

```
print_r(Kohana::modules());
```

You should see database module and path to it, then you can check that path and see if modules\database\classes\model\database.php file exist.
If path and file exist and was not changed then it should work.

Comment: I have enabled all the required modules in bootstrap.php